# pointers deference in c

Tags: c, linux, pointers, memory, heap-memory

When I tried to run this below two codes. For the first one I got segmentation fault error. I don't know why ?

```
 void main() {
       int *c1;
       *c1=10;
       printf("%d\n", *c1);
       printf("%d\n", sizeof(c1));
       printf("%d\n", sizeof(*c1));
       printf("%d\n", c1);
    }
```

When I run this below code, it prints output successfully.

```
   void main() {
      int *c1;
      *c1=10;
      printf("%d\n", *c1);
      printf("%d\n", sizeof(c1));
      printf("%d\n", sizeof(*c1));
      printf("%d\n", c1);
      int *c2=c1+1;
      printf("%d\n", c2);
      printf("%d\n",c2-c1);
   }
```

Can anyone explain the difference? As of understanding, I am assigning the value 10 to the pointer c1 holding address, trying to print the value at c1. So In both it should throw segv error. someone please clarify me

Comment: `c1` is *uninitialised* so you must not dereference it. The behaviour is undefined. Aside: use `%zu` for the sizeof, use `%p` for the pointer value. Take notice of all compiler warnings.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm check this.

Comment: Both programs use the uninitialized pointer `c1` which triggers undefined behaviour. You try to assign 1' to the memory address contained in `c1` but you never put any valid memory address into `c1` , instead `c1` contains an undetermined value

Comment: @gregni Tutorialspoint is a generally bad source and I wouldn't recommend it. As an example, in the very page you linked, `%x` is being used to print a pointer address when `%p` should be used instead.

Comment: I would recommend learning C first, before just doing random stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer c1 is not initialized and has indeterminate value.

```
int *c1;
```

So dereferencing the pointer

```
*c1=10;
```

results in undefined behavior.

Also you may not apply the subtract operation for pointers that do not point to elements of the same array as you are doing

```
c2-c1
```

Pay attention to that the value returned by the operator `sizeof` has the type `size_t`. It means that you need to use the conversion specifier `zu` instead of `d` in calls of `printf`

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(c1));
```

To output a pointer you need to use the conversion specifier p instead of d

```
printf("%p\n", ( void * )c1);
```

And according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall eb declared like

```
int main( void )
```